# UIImagePickerController in portrait mode inside UIPopoverController when view is locked for landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am using the following code for opening camera inside pop up view controller in iPad. Everything is working fine except it always open in landscape mode. I want to open pop camera in landscape mode. Parent view is locked to landscape mode.
Please let me know is it possible to change the camera frame size to portrait mode.

> ```
> UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
> imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
> imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
> imagePicker.delegate = self;
> UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
> self.popOverController = popover;
> popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 500);
> popover.delegate = self;
> [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 350,500) inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Subclassing UIImagePickerController

```
 @interface UAImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController {
}
@end

@implementation UAImagePickerController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
@end
```

Comment: its not working, I have tested this on iOS 6.0 an also implemented auto rotation function for this.

Comment: For IOS 6.0 you have to use - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate and - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations..

Comment: and can you tell me is this methods call or not?